# Extjs 4.1 Paging bar (Ext.toolbar.Paging) overflow issue

Tags: extjs, overflow, paging, toolbar, extjs4.1

I am using **Ext.toolbar.Paging** for a grid panel. When **resizing** the panel the **overflow** menu appears on the paging bar. But **total count** is not displayed correctly. Please check my paging bar.

**pageSizingCombo** is a defined object using a combobox for change paging size:

```
 Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Paging',{
                store:store,
                dock : 'bottom',
                itemId:'paging-bar-view-panel',
                displayMsg: '{0} - {1} of {2}',
                items:{
                    xtype : 'pageSizingCombo',
                    pageSizes : [10,20,25,50,75,100],
                    width : 50
                },
                displayInfo: true,
                enableOverflow: true
            })
```

**Paging bar without overflow menu.**

[image]

**Paging bar with overflow menu**

[image: when overflowing total count is incorrect it is displayed as "no record found"]

It's showing "**no records found**". Is there are any solution for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could dig up the problem lies with the tbtext component added to the paging toolbar found here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Paging.html#Ext-toolbar-Paging-method-initComponent. To get around this you could turn off the displayInfo setting to false by:

```
displayInfo: false
```

and then adjusting your item config as:

```
items:[{ 
         xtype : 'pageSizingCombo',
         pageSizes : [10,20,25,50,75,100],
         width : 50
       },
       '->',
       {
         xtype: 'text', 
         itemId: 'displayItem'
      }]
```

Note that this will not work if you change the value for the itemId for the text component. In other words it always has to be 'displayItem'.